# How select this element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, onclick

I've the following code :

```
<div class=myClass>
  <a href="#" id="click">Click for option Tata</a>
</div>

<div class="selectMultiContent">
 <ul class="selectMultiList library">
   <li data-value="517" class="">Tata</li>
   <li data-value="389" class="">Titi</li>
   <li data-value="387" class="">Toto</li
 </ul>
</div>
```

When I'm clicking on 'a' link, I want to simulate a click on the fisrt 'li' with a trigger.

But how to do that ? I'm looking to use triggers, but it seems difficult to use in this case.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a click handler which can select the `li` based on its `data-value` attribute like

```
$('#click').click(function(){
    $('.selectMultiList li[data-value="517"]').click()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by calling a JS method:

```
<a href="javascript:clickOnOption(517)" id="click">Click for option Tata</a>

function clickOnOption(activeElement){
    $('.selectMultiList li[data-value="'+activeElement+'"]').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can make it quite dynamic, just make sure the class and data-item attribute match

As an example I just made it alert the data value. If you change data-item to "titi" it would alert 389

Example:

```js
$('.clicker').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.' + $(this).attr('data-item')).trigger('click');
});

$('.library li').on('click', function () {
    alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myClass">
    <a href="#null" class="clicker" data-item="tata">Click for option Tata</a>
</div>
<div class="selectMultiContent">
    <ul class="selectMultiList library">
        <li data-value="517" class="tata">Tata</li>
        <li data-value="389" class="titi">Titi</li>
        <li data-value="387" class="toto">Toto</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstration, but I've no class on my 'li'